# Syntax Highlighter not working

Tags: bug, design, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed since the recent update Stack Overflow has undergone the syntax highlighting tool seems to be slightly off.

Property names seems to be highlighted as Classes:

[How to change the display name for LabelFor in razor in mvc3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651254/how-to-change-the-display-name-for-labelfor-in-razor-in-mvc3)

Look at the top rated answer, SmokingStatus is being coloured teal as if its a class, when it has already been declared as type String and SmokingStatus is just the name. Its making reading code snippets extremely confusing. Apologies if this has already been spotted or if I've got this wrong.

Comment: This is a stylesheet issue for a specific site, not an issue with the highlighter used across the network.

Comment: So nothing to do with google prettify?

Comment: Prettify is still adding the same classes to the same tags, the stylesheet then uses the same colours for two different classes.